# ffmpeg slide transition from right to left

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this script as a reference:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -loop 1 -i 2.jpg -loop 1 -i 3.jpg -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=480x600[v0];[0:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v1a][v1b];[1:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v2a][v2b];[2:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];[v0][v1a]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv0];[v1b][v2a]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv1];[v2b][v3]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv2];[vv0][vv1][vv2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [video]" -map "[video]" Slideoutput.mp4
```

This works by transitioning the images from left to right. What I need to do is transition images from right to left. I tried changing the signs but the result is not right.

What should I do to change the imgae tarnsition so that it is from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
x='W-min(t*W/0.5\,W)'
```

The image will first appear on the right and stop at x=0.

Comment: Thanks Gyan. What if we want to increase the duration from 5 seconds to 7 seconds. I just need to set the trim=duration=7, right?

Comment: not exactly as the left to right one  `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -loop 1 -i 2.jpg -loop 1 -i 3.jpg -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=480x600[v0];[0:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v1a][v1b];[1:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v2a][v2b];[2:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];[v0][v1a]overlay=x='W-min(t*W/0.5\,w+W)':shortest=1[vv0];[v1b][v2a]overlay=x='W-min(t*W/0.5\,w+W)':shortest=1[vv1];[v2b][v3]overlay=x='W-min(t*W/0.5\,w+W)':shortest=1[vv2];[vv0][vv1][vv2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [video]" -map "[video]" RightSlideoutput.mp4`

Comment: I used the above code and the first slide doesn't stop at all. The other slides keep moving as well. I can upload the generated videos and share the links so you can have a visual reference of what's wrong.

Comment: Link to the problem file:

[link](https://vimeo.com/user90930157/review/296596903/a321153657)

This second link is left to right which was the original and correct one:
[link](https://vimeo.com/user90930157/review/296597669/c464ce8449)

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same behavior in one of my application, where slide appears from right to left.

This is how i did, modifying the **Command**:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img01.png -loop 1 -i img02.png -loop 1 -i img03.png -filter_complex \
"nullsrc=size=480x600[v0];\
[0:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v1a][v1b];\
[1:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v2a][v2b];\
[2:v]trim=duration=5,scale=480x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];\
[v0][v1a]   overlay=x='max(w-(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv0];\
[v1b][v2a]  overlay=x='max(w-(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv1];\
[v2b][v3]   overlay=x='max(w-(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv2];\
[vv0][vv1][vv2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [video]" -map "[video]" Slideoutput.mp4
```

**Description:**
Key was to provide proper X value to overlay frame..

**Example:**
Overlay has width of : 480
we want to display overlay at x = 480 in first frame
then something like,
x = 460
x = 420
.
.
x = 0

thats how it looks like coming from right direction